# regular expression parse url parameter

Tags: php, regex

I'm having trouble retrieving a URL parameter from a string using regular expressions:

An example string could be

`some text and http://google.com/?something=this&tag=yahoo.com and more text`, and I would like to be able to find `yahoo.com` from this.

The caveat is that I need to ensure that the string begins with `http://google.com`, and not just search for `&tag=(.*)`

`preg_match("/google\.com\/.*&tag=(.*) $/", $subject, $matches)`

i'm hoping this matches anything with `google.com` followed by anything, followed by `&tag=` followed by a space. Ultimately the goal is to parse out all of the `tag=` values from `google.com` URLs.

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Update:

so I have this new regex: `/google\.com\/.*(tag=.*)/` but i'm not sure how to get it to end on a space after the URL

Comment: What's the issue with your code?

Comment: Why the space at the end of your pattern?

Comment: I'm hoping to match the end of the string with a space... (i should probably add `$`)

Comment: Do not hope. Create lit of URLs that you want to pass, other list of invalid ones and write unit test to check if your function does what you want it to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

get friendly with the [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function!

```
$pieces = parse_url('some text http://google.com/?something=this&tag=yahoo.com and whatever');
$query = explode('&', $pieces['query']);

parse_str($pieces['query'], $get);
array_walk($get, function(&$item){
    if (!$sp = strpos($item, ' ')) return;
    $item = substr($item, 0, $sp);
});

var_dump($get); // woo!
```

edit: thanks to Johnathan for the [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) function.

Comment: thanks, never used that - but the string in this example will be more text than just the URL

Comment: Don't forget [parse_str](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) to parse the query string.

Comment: @d-_-b, theres no problem that theres extra text, `parse_url` pulls it out.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the value of `tag` then the following regex will do the job:

```
$string = 'some text and http://google.com/?something=this&tag=yahoo.com
and more text
http://google.com/?something=this&tag=yahoo2.com&param=test
';
preg_match_all('#http://google.com\S+&tag=([^\s&]+)#', $string, $m);
print_r($m[1]);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => yahoo.com
    [1] => yahoo2.com
)
```

**Explanation**

- `http://google.com` : match `http://google.com`
- `\S+` : match non whitespace one or more times
- `&tag=` : match `&tag=`
- `([^\s&]+)` : match anything except whitespace and `&` one or more times and group it

If you want, you may even add `s?` after `http` to take in account for `https`, or add the `i` modifier to match case insensitive.

Comment: this is great! thanks! I'll review this in a little while... quick question, why the `#` at the start?

Comment: @d-_-b It's the modifier. I used `#` instead of `/` which you're using. Why ? Because if I use a different modifier than `/` then I wouldn't need to escape those slashes for example in `http://` :)