# Extract Two Value between special characters with Preg_Match

Tags: special-characters, preg-match-all

Hello I want to Extract the username and Password value with one preg_match_all

$url='http://xxxxxxxx.com:80/get.php?username=xxxxxx&password=xxxxxx&type=m3u_plus';

I get wiht this explode where i want but i know is more effect with preg_match_all can you show me how.?

```
$url_ext = parse_url($url);
$username=explode ("&",explode("=",$url_ext['query'])[1]);
$password=explode ("&",explode("=",$url_ext['query'])[2]);
```

I try with this code but not working

```
$lotes_fil='~https?://.\=(.+?)&~';
preg_match_all($lotes_fil,$url,$link_pre);
```

Comment: `parse_url` is certainly better than `preg_match_all`, why do you want to change?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18114891/372239

Comment: Sometimes the URL has a 3rd condition and the PARSE gets confused and changes the Arrary

Comment: So what? Have you seen the link I gave above? Use `parse_url` and then `parse_str`. This is faster and more maintainable than a complex regex that have to deal with unknown number of paratemeters in random order.

Comment: Let me use parse_str and I'll tell you

Comment: Really is a good options...
But I would like to know how it would be in Preg_Mach_all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to use `parse_url` and `parse_str` like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18114891/372239).

But, if you really  want a regex, this does the job:

`(?<=[?&])([^&=\r\n]+)=([^&=\r\n]+)`

```
preg_match_all('/(?<=[?&])([^&=\r\n]+)=([^&=\r\n]+)/', $url, $matches);
```

The parameter name is in group 1, the value in group 2

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/SUYkuG/1)

Comment: Yes, I'm already using Parse and it's working fine for me. Also try your Regex and it works. Now as a last curiosity, how do you manage to generate that Regex that looks so complex, I understand that with experience but there is always some tool that supports you. Can you recommend any?

Comment: @Torronf: Here is a usefull site: https://www.regular-expressions.info/  You can also use https://regex101.com/ to test your regex.